# What is prometheus-rsocket-proxy and how to use it?

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, micrometer, rsocket

I have a Spring Boot based short-live service.

Until now, I used PushGateway to send metrics to Prometheus.

I encountered [this repository](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/prometheus-rsocket-proxy) and I'm trying to understand how do I setup the proxy. It's not clear from the docs.

Thanks

Comment: It look like it solves for the cases where you can't tell a collector to collect from your service, and want a better model than the push gateway.

Your app connects outwards to the proxy, and accepts incoming requests for prometheus metrics.

Comment: @YuriSchimke, how do you run the proxy? How is it different from PushGateway?

Comment: I haven't used it, but was answering the "What is" part of your question.